# Check is current CGPoint in CMenu

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Can we check if CGPoint have touched in CMenu item?
I need return YES if point in button and NO if point didn't in button.

```
 -(BOOL)isButton:(CGPoint)point
    {
        if(controlMode == 1)
        {

            for (CCMenu *menu in self.children)
            {

                    // If point in button
                    return YES;
                    // else
                    return NO;


                }
            }

        }
        return NO;
    }
```

Menu buttons:

```
CCMenuItem *pauseItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"pause.png" selectedImage:@"pause_.png" target:self selector:@selector(pauseGame:)]; 
CCMenuItem *resetItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"reset.png" selectedImage:@"reset_.png" target:self selector:@selector(resetClicked:)]; 
CCMenu *Menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:pauseItem,resetItem, nil];
Menu.position = ccp(450, 40); 
[Menu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:5]; 
[self addChild:Menu];
```

Comment: Is your point a touch location?

Comment: Yes. My point is touch location

Answer (score 2):

Since the point you are refering to is a touch (from comments), if you are touching a button on the menu, that item will be selected.

```
-(BOOL) isAButtonSelected
{
    for(CCMenuItem* item in menu.children)
    {
        if(item.isSelected) return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: 2012-04-15 19:27:09.054 AppTest[468:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCSprite isSelected]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x37d100'

Comment: You've used a CCSprite. I used a CCMenuItem

Comment: CCMenuItem *pauseItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"pause.png" selectedImage:@"pause_.png" target:self selector:@selector(pauseGame:)];
    CCMenuItem *resetItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"reset.png" selectedImage:@"reset_.png" target:self selector:@selector(resetClicked:)];
    
    CCMenu *Menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:pauseItem,resetItem,
                    nil];
    Menu.position = ccp(450, 40);
    [Menu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:5];
    [self addChild:Menu];

Menu init. Maybe something wrong here?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to read but I can't see any problems. Consider adding this to your question.

Answer (score 1):

you can try smth like this

```
for(CCMenuItem* item in yourMenu.children)
{
    CCPoint localPoint = [item convertToNodeSpace:point];
    if( (localPoint.x <= item.contentSize.width) && (localPoint.y <= item.contentSize.height) )
    {
        // in that case your point is in this item of your CCMenu
    }
}
```